# How to define a DataType column in DataTable?

Tags: .net, datatable, types, type-conversion

I have a requirement to store the some data in a datatable. The columns in the table are:
-ID
-Text
-Value
-DataType
How should I define the table columns so that the DataType column stores native and composite types?

Currently I am storing it as

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DataType", typeof(string)));
```

Later in my program I am trying to parse the values and depending on the datatype I show the control. Like, if the datatype is int then show textbox, if bool then show dropdown.

I am sure there will be an easier way to do this. Please suggest how to achieve this functionality? Example code will help me in understanding it better. Thanks!

Comment: It should work this way. What is the problem?

Comment: Let me explain again as I couldn't before. I want a way to determine the datatype stored either in datatable column or to simplify, in a string variable. Like string sType = "System.Boolean". Once determined, then I will put the control (textbox, dropdown etc). But I also, want to populate the control with standard values. For Example: If it is boolean type then, I need the dropdown to have true and false values. If the variable has "System.Drawing.Color" then the dropdown should have all the system colors. I have a code that do this exactly, but instead of a datatable I have a class object.

Answer (score 2):

Creating columns like DataType and Value in a `DataColumn` or DBMS is usually symptomatic of the [Inner-platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect), where you try to create a typed database inside your typed database by ignoring the type definitions in your database.

Don't do that. `DataColumn`s already support typed data, querying the schema, and joining tables that contain heterogeneous data. Store ints as ints , booleans as booleans, and you won't have to parse anything. You can determine the data type of a `DataColumn` with:

```
var dc = new System.Data.DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
bool isInt = dc.DataType.Equals(typeof(int));
```

Comment: You are right but in my case I am getting a datatype column separetly that I need to parse so that I can provide the correct web control on the page. I can't change the data coming to me. "DataType" column mentioned in my example, contains ints, booleans, strings, colors, myobject etc. The example is something like a property grid. Did I make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code a little easier by doing the following:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("DataType", typeof(string));
```

There is no need to use the datacolumn constructor.

Comment: Sure :) It looks cleaner. Any idea on how can I use a method similar to GetStandardValuesSupported() for the DataType column in the datatable? I guess this method will help me in determining the type and the values it can have. Right?

Answer (score -1):

So, you are really creating some sort of authoring tool. You define your datatypes in a database and then, create the controls on the fly when then data is read?

Ok, so rather than store the default values (true, false) in the database, what about storing them in the controls. For example you now a checkbox must have default values of true/false, A txtbax has default values of blank etc.

Or, yu could extend your database to hold a list of possible values for a field. By that I mean you might have a row that reads

Id=5, Text='Selected'. Value='False', Type='System.Boolean'

Then in another table

Id=5, Value=True, default=false
Id=5, Value=false, default=true

or, for a string

Id=5, Text='Selected'. Value='UK', Type='System.Text'

Id=5, Value='UK', default=true
id=5, value='USA', default=false

If you do this, then you can drop the value from the first table..

Not totally sure that helps?

Comment: That is another solution but what if the datatype of one of my variables is Color or a struc or enum? I want a way to get the information from the code itself. I don't want to store the defaults in the database. Something similar to the following 
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myobject).